# Support Vector library not working

Tags: android, vector, android-support-library, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have used `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in my gradle file.

```
 static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

I have used the static code in my application file.

The image view in my layout file looks like this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_img"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/topBar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@color/newsArticleText"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/newspaper_white" />
```

Everything works alright when there is an image to be displayed but when there is no image the default vector `@drawable/newspaper_white` should be loaded but instead its just blank.

[image: Item View]

As you can see the 2nd image loaded but the item before that just skipped the drawable entirely,the grey color is due to the background being applied to the image view through `android:background="@color/newsArticleText"`.

This is part of a recycler view,i am using glide to load the images and while unbinding the item i am setting it to the default vector using

```
holder.getImageView().setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.newspaper_white));
```

It still doesn't show the original vector.This is being run on a device with android version 19.

Comment: are you using v26 support library?

Comment: @q126y yes i am

Comment: Either it is broken or something has changed. I am also getting same issue. but it works fine on revision 25.